# Firebase Web retrieve more specific data and sort it

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database structure in Firebase:

[firebaseDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldUP9.jpg)

Each object contains category and sectionIndex which correspond to a chapter and its sort order.

I am trying to grab those datas in order to display it in my menu.

I can acces to the DB with this code below:

`firebase.database().ref().on("value", snapshot => {console.log(snapshot.val());} ,error => {console.log("Error: " + error.code);} );`

There is the result in the console:

[consoleScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkp5U.png)

My question is how can I enter in each object (0,1,2,3,4,...,45), grab the category value and sort it in order following the sectionIndex and avoid to duplicate the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has a set of queries outlined in the docs which allow you to do some basic manipulation of data. In your case, it looks like you'll want to use [orderByChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild) to sort your entire database object by sectionIndex. You can then specify how many you want to get at one time using the [limitToFirst or limitToLast](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#limitToFirst) parameters.

Then, when you get your snapshot, just grab all the categoryValues and do what you want with them. Rather than using .on("value") like you are currently, it's probably easier to use .on('child_added') like in their example:

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref("dinosaurs");
  ref.orderByChild("height").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key + " was " + snapshot.val().height + " m tall");
});
```

It shouldn't be to hard for you to apply this to your case.

Remember also that depending on what else you want to do with this data, and depending on how many items your're going to have, it may be easier to do the sorting on the client side (i.e. rather than letting Firebase do the sorting, make your computer/app do the sorting)